# ForEach inside API does not work properly

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angualr 4.

i have an array.

Here is my array;

```
this.bookings = [
    {
     'id':'dsjdsfhkdsjhfjkds01'
    },
    {
     'id':'dsjdsfhkdsjhfjkds01'
    }
]
```

I need retrieve data from database based on id.

Here is my script.

```
let scope = this;
scope.bookings.forEach(function(BookingItem){
  var bId = BookingItem.id;
  console.log("BId",bId);
  scope.Bservice.getbooking(scope.at,bId).subscribe(booking => {
    var responseVal = booking;
  })
})
```

I need  like forEach Take on firstvalue then get retrive data from database.After going to second value of booking then get data from database.

But i consoled value of  `bId`.

ForEach taken on id values one by one After retreive data from database.

How can i fix this pblm.

Kindly advice me,

Thanks.

Comment: same bid value taken by program , is that issue

Comment: @PranayRana.Thanks for ur comment.Sorry its my mistake.I updated my ques.Kindly check it.

Comment: sorry to say you but not getting thins at all

Comment: Please check the answer , you have to do like that , please resolve syntax error if you find any

Comment: is hat worked for you ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `api` call response takes some time, you should wait for the response untill it is recieved.

You can use `Observable forkJoin` which works like a promise and processes all requests in loop and returns response.

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

let observables = new Array();

this.bookings.forEach(function(booking){
    observables.push(this.Bservice.getbooking(this.at,booking.id));
})

Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe(
    res => console.log(res),
    error => console.log('Error: ', error)
);
```

[Here is a documentation for forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am not understading you code at full but you have to do like this

You have to loop throught `bookings` array and than in argument of `foreach` you need vriable name not name of you class ,

Another thing is if you go in loop, you last returned value from ajax request will override vlaue of your variable , so better to store response in array thats why below code use array to store you response for each id.

```
let responseFromServer = new Array<any>();    

this.bookings.forEach((bookingItem) => {
   var bId=bookingItem.id;
   console.log("BId",bId);
   scope.Bservice.getbooking(scope.at,bId).subscribe(booking=>{
      let response = new ResponseFromServer();
      responseFromServer.Add(booking);
   });
});
```